# How to measure complete response time (request in to response received by client ) in Play! framework?

Tags: logging, playframework, netty, grafana

I'm a new user of playframework.
In a project of mine, I want to measure how long it takes from when a HTTP request comes in until the last byte of the response has been received by the client. I'm calling this period of time "response time".
In a netty log, I can see:

```
2016-11-17 10:32:00,712 [DEBUG] from io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler in netty-event-loop-3 - [id: 0xb4fb943a, L:/127.0.0.1:9001 - R:/127.0.0.1:50871] WRITE: DefaultFullHttpResponse(decodeResult: success, version: HTTP/1.1, content: ReadOnlyByteBufferBuf(ridx: 0, widx: 655, cap: 655/655))

2016-11-17 10:32:00,713 [DEBUG] from io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler in netty-event-loop-3 - [id: 0xb4fb943a, L:/127.0.0.1:9001 - R:/127.0.0.1:50871] FLUSH

2016-11-17 10:32:00,713 [DEBUG] from io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler in netty-event-loop-3 - [id: 0xb4fb943a, L:/127.0.0.1:9001 - R:/127.0.0.1:50871] FLUSH

2016-11-17 10:37:19,311 [DEBUG] from io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler in netty-event-loop-3 - [id: 0xb4fb943a, L:/127.0.0.1:9001 ! R:/127.0.0.1:50871] INACTIVE

2016-11-17 10:37:19,312 [DEBUG] from io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler in netty-event-loop-3 - [id: 0xb4fb943a, L:/127.0.0.1:9001 ! R:/127.0.0.1:50871] UNREGISTERED
```

I can get the response time from the log (from WRITE to FLUSH?), but is there any way to get the "response time" more easily?  What I need is to measure the "response time" as a metric and log it or send it to Grafana.

Thanks everyone!

Comment: This [link](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/JavaHttpFilters#A-simple-logging-filter) might help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- use a library that will collect the metrics from the framework and push them to a metric backend. [Kamon](http://kamon.io/integrations/web-and-http-toolkits/play/) is a nice library with a play integration
- write your own code to record the metric. For this you will need to look into [play filters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaHttpFilters)